# Output of IDX in Kmeans?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a 1000x6 dataset and using the below kmeans script is fine but when I want to output one of the clusters it only comes out as one column?

```
%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 100, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',6);

%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 5, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 100, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')

%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);

%% Assign data to clusters
% calculate distance (squared) of all instances to each cluster centroid
D = zeros(numObservarations, K);     % init distances
for k=1:K
%d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
D(:,k) = sum( ((data - repmat(clusters(k,:),numObservarations,1)).^2), 2);
end

% find  for all instances the cluster closet to it
[minDists, clusterIndices] = min(D, [], 2);

% compare it with what you expect it to be
sum(clusterIndices == clustIDX)

% Output cluster data to K datasets
K1 = data(clustIDX==1)
K2 = data(clustIDX==2)... etc
```

Shouldnt `K1 = data(clustIDX==1)` output the full row information? Not just one column but six like the original dataset?  Or is this just outputting the distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
K1 = data(clustIDX==1)
K2 = data(clustIDX==2)
```

with

```
K1 = data(clustIDX==1,:)
K2 = data(clustIDX==2,:)
```

The first one retrieves only the first column of corresponding rows. The second one should fix it, I've tried and it works.

Comment: Hi thanks quenis, that worked. Have only used matlab a handful of times so not so sure on all the syntax! +1